# common lisp equivalent of a python idiom

Tags: python, lisp, common-lisp

How do I run an equivalent of this Python command in Lisp

```
from lib import func
```

For example, I want to use the `split-sequence` package, and in particular I only want the `split-sequence` method from that package.

Currently, I have to use it as `(split-sequence:split-sequence #\Space "this is a string")`.

But I what I want to do is `(split-sequence #\Space "this is a string")`.

How do I get access to the function directly without qualifying it with the package name?

Comment: What did you try to solve that problem? Stackoverflow is not for learning the basics of a programming language. There are some good introductory books and a language specification.

Comment: I did skim through Practical Common Lisp, and then jumped in. I picked up a lot about the language, and can start writing code. It's just some little things that I missed in the skimming. I find I learn the best if I just jump in. In PCL, there is a chapter that deals with these things, and I spent a lot of time trying to see if I could get `Intern` and `Keyword` to do this, before I posted here.

Comment: http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/programming-in-the-large-packages-and-symbols.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you want to do is simply:

```
(import 'split-sequence:split-sequence)
```

This works fine in a REPL, but if you want to organize your symbols, you'd better rely on packages.

```
(defpackage #:my-package 
   (:use #:cl)
   (:import-from #:split-sequence 
                 #:split-sequence))
```

The first ̀`split-sequence` is the package, followed by all the symbols that should be imported. In [`DEFPACKAGE`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_defpkg.htm) forms, people generally use either keywords or uninterned symbols like above in order to avoid interning symbols in the current package. Alternatively, you could use strings, because only the names of symbols are important:

```
 (defpackage "MY-PACKAGE"
   (:use "CL")
   (:import-from "SPLIT-SEQUENCE" "SPLIT-SEQUENCE"))
```

Comment: Note that, although this is the right answer, the semantics are fairly different than python's: in particular the CL idiom means that a single name (symbol) is visible in both packages, while in Python a single object is referred to by two different names.